# How to construct an Authorization header that is base64 encoded?

Tags: php, curl, basic-authentication

I am building a web application using using CTM (Call Tracking Metrics) API in PHP-cURL language. To authorize with the API they use Basic Authentication method to construct an Authorization header that is base64 encoded.

The [documentation](https://postman.calltrackingmetrics.com/#d9e3f5ee-ba47-4e4a-a2db-d749d2072720) for getting list of accounts. Here I am facing difficulties in assigning basic auth in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: {{Basic Auth}}',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
),
```

I have tried assigning it like below

```
$encoded_string = base64_encode('a20374d463f8a02b68fdc3bed8eb8bb4bb5a0c6:16ebe4fe438b2bdf2e80599baec8f7a6bbc4');

// echo $encoded_string;

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.calltrackingmetrics.com/api/v1/accounts',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: {{'.$encoded_string.'}}',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));
```

Above code shows error `{"authentication":"failed"}`.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to assign basic auth ?

Comment: I think the brackets `{{` and `}}` are just placeholders in the documentation and should not be part of the header

Comment: I have tried removing brackets but the result did not changed. Am I creating encoded string correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the brackets and try this

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Basic '.$encoded_string,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
```